# Need to get gridview rows to vbnet code behind

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, vb.net, gridview

I have an application that drags and drops data from many gridviews into a new gridview. Since the rows are added using jquery, they do not appear when I use the code behind to loop through the new rows. I see only the original rows from before dropping new rows. When I inspect the browser, all of the rows are present. I apparently need a way to perhaps use json and ajax at the client to create a string which can be read or sent to the code behind. Would someone please explain (maybe with an example if you have time) how to go about this? Thanks!

So far I have only tried to loop through the "new" gridview to no avail. I do not know how to proceed with any other options.